# CSS is not minimized in the build file using Parcel.js

Tags: css, reactjs, build, minimize, parsel

I use **Parcel.js** for building.
I do not get all css minimized when I run "**yarn build**".
I see this applies places where **styled-components** is used.
This package is extracted from **'vui' (my companies design system)** as '**styled**'
The question: How to minimized CSS in this case? Thx :)

```
"build": "parcel build src/index.html --no-source-maps && parcel build src/index-ie.html --no-source-maps && parcel build src/error.html --no-source-maps",
```

[image]

[image]